# How to persist JavaFX properties in SQLite using ORMLite?

Tags: java, ormlite

I am using JavaFX to create an app and I need (it would be very cool) to persist JavaFX properties such as `SimpleStringProperty` or `SimpleObjectProperty`.

I've seen [this issue](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/issues/106) (now closed) that make use of the `SimpleStringPropertyPersister` class.

But, I don't actually have this class.

I've tried using the `SerializablePersister` class as my persister class, and ORMLite didn't send me a huge error. But I'm not sure that all JavaFX properties (at least the ones that I want to use) are Serializable, as in the javadoc it is not.

I'm using the last version available at the maven central :

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
  <artifactId>ormlite-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

> I am using JavaFX to create an app and I need (it would be very cool) to persist JavaFX properties such as SimpleStringProperty or SimpleObjectProperty.

The first link in a search on google for "ormlite custom persister" brought me to the [documentation for customer persisters](https://ormlite.com/docs/custom-persister).  Shocking.  I spent a lot of time on the ORMLite docs so they should be helpful.  There also is source code [example of a custom date persister](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-jdbc/tree/master/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/examples/datapersister).

To quote from the docs:

> When defining a data persister class from scratch, you could extend one of the other data type persisters or the BaseDataType class. You will need to define the following methods.
>
> - `parseDefaultString` – Converts a default string into a SQL argument suitable to be loaded into the database.
> - `resultToSqlArg` – Uses the DatabaseResults object to get the right SQL argument type out of the results.
> - `sqlArgToJava` – Converts the SQL argument to the associated Java class.

Comment: If you're seing this, I recommand you to see a build-in persister to understand how it works. [BigIntegerType.java](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/field/types/BigIntegerType.java). The two key methods here are `#javaToSqlArg(...)` and `#sqlArgToJava(...)`.